# VueJS Loading template component via code?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to make a template component that I can use later on in my project. However I'm having a bit of a hard time showing it on the element I want via code.

The code I have so far is as such.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-alert show dismissible variant="danger" v-show="elementVisible">
        <i class="mdi mdi-block-helper mr-2"></i>{{ text }}
    </b-alert>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "alertDanager",
  props: {
    text: null
  },
  data() {
    return {
      elementVisible: true
    };
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => (this.elementVisible = false), 5000);
  }
};
</script>
```

I am trying to call this on an action by this

I import it

```
import dangerAlert from "@/components/Alerts/danger";
```

Then on the function I want to call it on I do this

```
const error = new dangerAlert({ propsData: { text: "Error message" } });
error.$mount("#error");
```

However it just gives me an error saying

```
_components_Alerts_danger__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default is not a constructor
```

So I'm not sure how to fix this or do what I need to do. I've tried googling but can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Component imported is not a constructor and it should extends a constructor and to use that you should use `Vue.extend()`

Vue.extend() is a class inheritance method. Its task is to create a sub-class of Vue and return the constructor.

so instead of this

```js
const error = new dangerAlert({ propsData: { text: "Error message" } });
error.$mount("#error");
```

make it like this

```js
const DangerAlertExtended= Vue.extend(dangerAlert);
const error = new DangerAlertExtended({ propsData: { text: "Error message" } });
error.$mount("#error");
```

Comment: I  might need to open a new question for this, but is there anyway to make it mount without destroying the error div? Because at the moment, it works fine however it can't make a second call as it has overwritten the error div.

Comment: If I were you, I will mount it and once the component will destroy I recreate it

Comment: Maybe this is me being stupid but how can I recreate it if it overwrites the div I need it to mount to?